# RSpec referencing child record in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm new to RSpec and something I'm continuously having trouble with is understanding what records are in/out of scope. See below for an example. I'm creating a series of records via FactoryGirl. For example, I create a user and then in the before block I sign_in with that user. This always seems to work fine. But whenever I start trying to use records that are children of previously created records I seem to get into trouble. For example with group. Group requires a user and a group_type. Whenever I try to do something with these kind of records I hit a "Called id for nil" error. I've tried "puts group.name" and I can see that the group is being created but for some reason once the "visit group_path(group)" line executes the record no longer exists. I know I'm missing something pretty fundamental here. Appreciate any help as this has been driving me crazy.

```
describe "activities page" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:group_type) { FactoryGirl.create(:group_type) }
  let!(:group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group, user: user, group_type: group_type) }

 before do      
   sign_in user
   visit group_path(group)
   click_button "Check In"
 end
```

Error:

```
1) Activity pages activities page 
 Failure/Error: visit group_path(group)
 RuntimeError:
   Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Adding Group show method:

```
def show
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @members = @group.members.paginate(page: params[:page])
  cookies[:group_id] = @group.id

  # Set Pusher chat
  @chat = Chat.find_by_group_id(@group.id)
  @user = current_user
  @messages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => ["chat_id = ?", @chat.id.to_s])
end
```

Comment: What does the `show` method in your GroupsController look like?

Comment: Added above. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Is `@chat` nil? Your test doesn't seem to create any Chats associated with the Groups it creates.

Comment: Are you using capybara or something else? If you are using capybara, sign_in user won't work, since it runs in a separate browser process, you need to actually visit the new session page and log in.

Comment: An associated `Chat` and `GroupMember` is created as part of the Group `create` method. I'm assuming if something went wrong with that create call I would get an error when I try something like "puts group.name"? I am using capybara and have been doing things like `sign_in user` followed by `visit some_path` in a number of tests. One difference here is that I usually do something like `visit some_path(user)`, here I'm passing `group` to the path.

Comment: Never got this solved. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is the fact you are using `let!`.
The difference between them is that the non bang version is lazy. Its get evaluated only when the variable is needed.
The bang version gets called before each example.
The problem here is the order the non-lazy examples. I really dont think you can guarantee the order they run. In your case, I believe let!(:group) is runnning before let!(group_type) runs causing this failure.